# Why ref and useRef hook is not working for TouchableOpacity element in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am using ref and useRef hook for TouchableOpacity element to access prop onPress() so that i can click on this using ref.current.props.onPress(); but I am getting TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Why ref and useRef hook is not working for TouchableOpacity element in react native.

Same is happening for RadioButton and CheckBox elements in react native. Could you please guide me for same.

I am using ref and useRef hook for TouchableOpacity element to access prop onPress() so that i can click on this using ref.current.props.onPress(); but I am getting TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Why ref and useRef hook is not working for TouchableOpacity element in react native

Same is happening for RadioButton and CheckBox elements in react native. Could you please guide me for same.

```
<TouchableOpacity ref={touchableOpacityRef} onPress={() => Alert.alert("Show")}>
</TouchableOpacity>

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    // Programmatically trigger a click event on TouchableOpacity
    touchableOpacityRef.current && touchableOpacityRef.current.props.onPress();
  };
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.